# Can't reload CollectionView with new fetched data from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

When I select a cell in the CategoryVc it should pop to the MainVc and display the new data in the CollectionView but it doesn't. It only load data when I run the app.
I checked and the chosenCategory var get the right String after selecting the cell and the refresh function gets called. I can't understand what wrong.

Edit: If I push the view controller instead of popping it, it works. But I need to pop it.

It also prints both the right chosenCategroy 

The mainVc is a UICollectionViewCell

MainVc

```
static var chosenCategory = "General"

    func fetchQuotes() {
        CATEGORIES_REF.child(QuoteCell.chosenCategory).observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
            let quoteId = snapshot.key

            CATEGORIES_REF.child(QuoteCell.chosenCategory).child(quoteId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> else { return }
                let quote = Quote(quoteId: quoteId, dictionary: dictionary)

                self.quotes.append(quote)
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
                print("second: \(QuoteCell.chosenCategory)")
            })
        }
    }

    func refresh() {
        quotes.removeAll()
        fetchQuotes()
        print(QuoteCell.chosenCategory)
    }
```

CategoryVc

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            QuoteCell.chosenCategory = "\(categories[indexPath.item])"
            quoteCell.refresh()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

one of the missing parts is not using main thread. When you use reloadData of collectionView use with main thread.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Then another thing is if you want to process anything in backward controller, I would recommmend you to use `Protocol / Delegates.`

Describe a protocol

```
protocol Handler:class{
    func reloadHandler()
}
```

Then extend it with your `MainController`. After extending use your own reload function in protocol's function.

```
extension MainController: Handler{

    func reloadHandler() {
            self.reload()
    }
}
```

Then delegate the protocol in target `ViewController`

```
class TargetController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: Handler?
}
```

Before the push the targetController, you must assign self to delegate of the `TargetController.`

```
var target = TargetController()
target.delegate = self
```

You set the delegation between two controllers. Now time to trigger your action. In target controller, when you trigger the `reload()`, use `delegate?.reloadHandler()`.

Comment: Hey @FrancescoLeoni, one of the problem is not using main thread when you reloadData function, but for figuring out why do you use pop?

Comment: I use pop to go back automatically to the previous view without creating more pushes

Comment: did you try it?

Comment: I don't understand where I have to put DispatchQueue and if the TargetController is the Controller that pushes. Thanks

Comment: Put it in the where you code collectionView.reloadData() in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're popping the view controller before refreshing you data. Try to change the order like:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     QuoteCell.chosenCategory = "\(categories[indexPath.item])"
     quoteCell.refresh()
     self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```